# How to decode lines encoded as base64 from file?

Tags: python, base64

I need to decode lines from a file.

Here is my code so far:

```
    def decode(self) -> list:
        """
        Decode file with key.

        For correct answer you have to convert file lines from base64 to utf-8.

        To decode one line you have to take a UNICODE value of a letter, subtract cipher step and take mod of 255.
        After that you have to convert that number back to a character.
        Example: key = 'test', decoded_data = "+%'"
        '+' -> (43 - 448) % 255 -> 'i' -> ... -> 'ice'

        :return: List of decoded lines
        """
        decoded_lines1 = []
        decoded_lines = []
        lines = self.read_code_from_file()
        for line in lines:
            decoded_lines.append(base64.b64decode(line).decode())
        for decoded_line in decoded_lines:
            for letter in decoded_line:
                decoded_lines1.append(chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255))
        return decoded_lines1
```

decoded_lines:

```
[')-.7)-\x06\x06AOO', '-57)-0\x06\x06JASJAOOASJ', ')07)2\x06\x06AJSAJAJOAJJAAO',...]
```

My output for some reason has all the letters individually, the small portion of output below is equal to the first list element of decoded_lines after decoding
My output:

```
['-', '1', '2', ';', '-', '1', '\n', '\n', 'E', 'S', 'S', ...]
```

Expected output:

```
['-12;-1\n\nESS', ...]
```

Is there any way to have the lines seperated by commas rather than each letter seperated by commas? The non-hardcoded key is equal to 1016.

Comment: Something like `"".join(decoded_lines1)` can help but you need to subdivide into lines first.

Comment: Thank you for the nudge into the correct direction, I am still unclear as to how to subdivide my output into lines, since the seperators are all the same and line length varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you append each character, one-by-one to `decoded_lines1` when you do

```
.append(chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255))
```

Instead, you want to do this to each character in `decoded_line`, make *one string* out of all the decoded characters, and *then* append *that string* to `decoded_lines1`.

```
for decoded_line in decoded_lines:
    new_line = []
    for letter in decoded_line:
       new_line.append(chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255))
    decoded_lines1.append("".join(new_line))
```

But you can simplify your code further by combining the `for line in lines` and `for decoded_line in decoded_lines` loops:

```
def decode(self):
    decoded_lines = []
    lines = self.read_code_from_file()
    for line in lines:
        decoded_line = base64.b64decode(line).decode()
        new_line = []
        for letter in decoded_line:
            new_line.append(chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255))
        decoded_lines.append("".join(new_line))
    return decoded_lines
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail what I've done wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in below code:

```
for decoded_line in decoded_lines:
    for letter in decoded_line:
        decoded_lines1.append(chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255))
```

Here, you are appending letter by letter to the list while you want to append decoded line into the list.

So, I have stored decoded letters into one string and then append it to the list.

```
for decoded_line in decoded_lines:
            temp=""
            for letter in decoded_line:
                temp=temp+chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255)
            decoded_lines1.append(temp)
```

Final code will be like below:

```
def decode(self) -> list:
        """
        Decode file with key.

        For correct answer you have to convert file lines from base64 to utf-8.

        To decode one line you have to take a UNICODE value of a letter, subtract cipher step and take mod of 255.
        After that you have to convert that number back to a character.
        Example: key = 'test', decoded_data = "+%'"
        '+' -> (43 - 448) % 255 -> 'i' -> ... -> 'ice'

        :return: List of decoded lines
        """
        decoded_lines1 = []
        decoded_lines = []            
        lines = self.read_code_from_file()
        for line in lines:
            decoded_lines.append(base64.b64decode(line).decode())
        for decoded_line in decoded_lines:
            temp=""
            for letter in decoded_line:
                temp=temp+chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255)
            decoded_lines1.append(temp)                
        return decoded_lines1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have only a single word in a line? it is a sentence of words? It consists of multiple words then your second loop should be on words then 3rd lop should be on letters. The code should be something like this

```
def decode(self) -> list:
        """
        Decode file with key.

        For correct answer you have to convert file lines from base64 to utf-8.

        To decode one line you have to take a UNICODE value of a letter, subtract cipher step and take mod of 255.
        After that you have to convert that number back to a character.
        Example: key = 'test', decoded_data = "+%'"
        '+' -> (43 - 448) % 255 -> 'i' -> ... -> 'ice'

        :return: List of decoded lines
        """
        decoded_lines1 = []
        decoded_lines = []
        lines = self.read_code_from_file()
        for line in lines:
            decoded_lines.append(base64.b64decode(line).decode())
        for decoded_line in decoded_lines:
            for word in decoded_line.split():
                docoded_word=''
                for letter in word:
                    docoded_word+=(chr((ord(letter) - sum([ord(i) for i in self.key])) % 255))
                decoded_lines1.append(docoded_word)
        return (decoded_lines1)
```